# Echo author ID in author.php

Tags: author, template-tags, id

This is probably a super simple question.

But how do I echo the ID of a user on author.php?

I've tried

```
the_author_meta('ID')
```

But it didn't seem to want to work. I want to echo it at the end of a URL, for example;

http:///www.domain.com/author/sampleauthor-id

Obviously, where "id" is that particular author's ID

Any ideas?

Comment: Not the permalinks, its for a modified version of the UserPhoto plugin.

I want to hardcode a particular image link into author.php and as each user's images are appeneded with their author ID I need to include that in the link

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this code.

```
$author = get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'author_name' ) );
echo $author->ID;
```

Alternatively, if author name has not been set use:

```
if ( $author_id = get_query_var( 'author' ) ) { $author = get_user_by( 'id', $author_id ); }
```

*credit @AndyAdams in the easily missed comments bellow*

Comment: This gives me a 500 internal server error

Comment: Are you sure it is because of the above code.. could I have a look at your author.php?

Comment: `$author = get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'author_name' ) );` gave no problems, it was the `echo author->ID;` that caused the error for some reason

Comment: Oops there is a typo.. its echo $author->ID... notice the '$'. Updated the answer.

Comment: Both of you missed a dollar sign. `echo $author->ID;`

Comment: Perfect!! I should have noticed the $ was missing, my bad. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: This will only work if `author_name` is set. Without pretty permalinks, you'll need to check for the `author` query var as well: `if ( $author_id = get_query_var( 'author' ) ) { $author = get_user_by( 'id', $author_id ); }`

Answer (score 11):

Try this simply code

```
if (is_author()){
    $author = get_queried_object();
    $author_id = $author->ID;
}
```

Comment: A simpler way to do this would be `$author_id = get_queried_object_id();`

Answer (score 2):

if `var_dump(the_author_meta('ID'))` is Null your author has no posts.

Try use echo `$author` if you call it inside `author.php`