# Give permission to admin to see user's page

Tags: php

I'm writing a code for author.php . I access this by: `http://example.com/author/{user_nicename}`
Imagine there are some users (Including 1 Admin, 4 or 5 editors, and so on ...)
Now when users click on above URL, They see their own Information.
I want to give permission to Admin and Editors to see the other arbitrary users Information.
How can i do that? This is a part of my code in author.php :

```
<?php
get_header();
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT display_name 
                               FROM wp_introduction 
                               INNER JOIN wp_users 
                               ON costumer_id = ID 
                               WHERE $introducer_id = $user_id" );

var_dump($result);
get_sidebar();
get_footer();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$user_id = get_current_user_id()`, you want to get the ID of the author by doing something like

```
$author = get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'author_name' ) );
```

or

```
if ( $author= get_query_var( 'author' ) ) { $author = get_user_by( 'id', $author_id ); }
```

And then use like

```
 $user_id = $author->ID;
```

Source: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/35251/47406